# Script to move first 3 characters of filename to the end

Tags: vbscript, rename, wsh

I have a directory full of files that I need to rename. For each file, I need to take the first three characters of the filename and move them to the end of the filename before the extension. 
So 003999999.wav would become 999999003.wav.

The scripting language doesn't really matter. It just needs to work in Windows. This seems like it'd be an easy script using vbscript and I'm currently doing some reading, but figured I'd see if someone already has something like this that would work.

Edit - So I think I've found how to do this, except the part on getting the filename characters. Here's what I have.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Directory")


For Each strFile in objFolder.Files
arrNames = Split(strFile.Name, ".")
If arrNames(1) = "mp3" Then

    Set objstart = objFSO.Range(0,3)
    Set objend = objFSO.Range(4,17)
    strNewName = "C:\Directory\" & objend.Text & objstart.Text & ".mp3"

    objFSO.MoveFile strFile.Path, strNewName
End If
Next
```

Comment: What do you do if the name is already used?

Comment: That absolutely won't be an issue based on how these files originally get their name. BUT, since I know it's bad practice to just hope it never happens, I'd say append a (1), (2), (3) to the end of the filename if it happens. So in the event 999999003.wav exists, use 999999003(1).wav.

But in reality, it won't ever be an issue.

Comment: you could use Scripting.FileSystemObject.GetExtensionName for the file extension (wav, mp3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script. I used simple string functions to manipulate each filename.

```
'Rename Files
'============
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strFile, intLength, firstThree, restofName, strNewName

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Directory")

For Each strFile in objFolder.Files

    'Get files by extension
    If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFile.Name) = "mp3" Then

        'Use instr to get the location of the "." and subtract 1 for the "."
        intLength = InStr(1,strFile.Name,".",1)-1

        'Use the Left function to get the first three characters of the filename
        firstThree = Left(strFile.Name,3)

        'Use the Mid function to get the rest of the filename subtract 3 for the file extension
        restofName = Mid(strFile.Name,4,intLength -3)

        strNewName = "C:\Directory\" & restofName & firstThree & ".mp3"
        objFSO.MoveFile strFile.Path, strNewName

    End If
Next

WScript.Echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the fictional .Range method, use a regular expression:

```
>> s1 = "003999999.wav"
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "(\d{3})(\d+)(\.wav)"
>> s2 = r.Replace(s1, "$2$1$3")
>> WScript.Echo s2
>>
999999003.wav
```

to cut three digits (\d{3}), the other digits (d+), and the (escaped) dot followed by the extension (wav) from the input string and re-arange the 3 parts in the .Replace.

Comment: Indeed. The Range method was something I saw on The Scripting Guys. It was being used to read part of a .doc to do something similar to what I'm doing. I crossed my fingers and put it in. Obviously incorrect. Thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of [JP's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16680093/1630171):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Directory").Files
  extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)
  If LCase(extension) = "mp3" Then
    basename = fso.GetBaseName(f.Name)
    f.Name = Mid(basename, 4) & Left(basename, 3) & "." & extension
  End If
Next
```

In batch you'd do it like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (C:\Directory\*.mp3) do (
  set basename=%%~nf
  ren "%%~ff" "!basename:~3!!basename:~0,3!%%~xf"
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly though, when I get to 30 files to be renamed, it doesn't do it correctly. Instead it is putting the first 3 characters in the middle at 12,13,14 rather than at the end which would be 15,16,17.